# Find a certain text in a cell and write in another cell

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a cell A1 which has following sentence "The color is orange" and I want to search this sentence and find if it has word orange, if yes then write Orange in the cell B1, if not then search for Black, if yes write Black, if not find for Green and so on. I have to search for 10 different colors. I need a simple excel formula not VBA.

Answer (score 5):

Something like:

```
=IFERROR(CHOOSE(MATCH(TRUE,ISNUMBER(SEARCH({"red","orange","black","yellow"},A1)),0),"red","orange","black","yellow"),"")
```

Note the array constant within the SEARCH function, and the matching options, in order, for the CHOOSE function

This second method using LOOKUP also works, and can use two array constants, which means you could easily list the colors in a range of cells and use the range reference in the formula:

```
=IFERROR(LOOKUP(2,1/ISNUMBER(SEARCH({"red","orange","black","yellow"},A1)),{"red","orange","black","yellow"}),"")
```

or, using range references:

```
=IFERROR(LOOKUP(2,1/ISNUMBER(SEARCH($I$1:$I$10,A1)),$I$1:$I$10),"")
```

Note that if using this technique, there can be no blank cells in I1:I10.
I have assumed only a single color will be listed in each cell you are checking.

If there might be multiple colors in A1, with the first (...CHOOSE(MATCH...) formula, list the colors in the order of priority; with the last (...LOOKUP(...) formula, list the colors in reverse order of priority.